# Oracle analytical query

Tags: sql, oracle

All, I need some help with writing a query, here is the snipped of data...

```
TABLE_NAME                                SIZE_BYTES      DATE
----------------------------------------  --------------- ---------
TABLE_A                                   346,817,560,576 17-SEP-16         
TABLE_A                                   346,817,560,576 18-SEP-16         
TABLE_A                                   369,046,323,200 19-SEP-16         
TABLE_A                                   413,623,386,112 20-SEP-16         
TABLE_A                                   466,840,715,264 21-SEP-16
TABLE_B                                   42895409152     17-SEP-16
TABLE_B                                   42962518016     18-SEP-16
TABLE_B                                   43163844608     19-SEP-16
TABLE_B                                   43365171200     20-SEP-16
TABLE_B                                   43566497792     21-SEP-16
```

17-SEP-2016 is the baseline and growth is calculated per day, so on 19-SEP-16 data grew by taking 19-SEP-2016 size_bytes less 18-SEP-16 size_bytes.

What I'm hoping to achieve is to show data in this format

```
TABLE_NAME    DATE        SIZE_DELTA
------------- ----------- --------------
TABLE_A       17-SEP-16 346,817,560,576
              18-SEP-16 0
              19-SEP-16 22,228,762,624
              20-SEP-16 44,577,062,912
              21-Sep-16 53,217,329,152
TABLE_B       17-Sep-16 42895409152
              18-Sep-16 67108864
              19-Sep-16 201326592
              20-Sep-16 201326592
              21-Sep-16 201326592
```

Comment: ?? What do you mean by "size_bytes" as a comma-separated string of four different numbers? (And, whatever you mean by it, why is the second row in the OUTPUT, table! for 18-SEP-16, just a 0, and not 0,0,0,0?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LAG function: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions082.htm#SQLRF00652

```
SELECT table_name, date,
       size_bytes - lag( size_bytes, 1, 0 ) 
                    OVER ( partition by table_name order by date ) As SIZE_DELTA
FROM tablename;
```

Comment: How does the solution work with the OP's inputs though? Meaning, the comma-separated strings of numbers?

Comment: @mathguy I guess that it works very well for him, because OP accepted the answer and thanked for it.

Comment: Thank you, that is brilliant! And it answers my curiosity perfectly.

Comment: I just wrapped the `size_bytes - lag( size_bytes, 1, 0 ) 
                    OVER ( partition by table_name order by date )` with `to_char(size_bytes - lag( size_bytes, 1, 0 ) 
                    OVER ( partition by table_name order by date ),'999,999,999,999')` for my final output report